# How to display results of a php method in an html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I've built a contest system where users submit tickets then one is randomly chosen to win, and now I'm trying to figure out a way to display to users the tickets they have already submitted. Each ticket has an id, a date, and an invoicenumber. I want to display all the invoice numbers that a user has submitted so far.

Here is the method I have in my methods page. (I've organized my methods into one php file and then i just call them when needed.)

```
function GetSubmittedBallots()
{
    if(!$this->CheckLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Not logged in!");
        return false;
    }

    $user_rec = array();
    if(!$this->GetUserFromEmail($this->UserEmail(),$user_rec))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $qry = "SELECT invoicenumber FROM entries WHERE user_id = '".$user_rec['id_user']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                      {
     echo   $row['invoicenumber'];
                      }

}
```

and then on my html page that I want it to echo on, i just call it

```
<?php GetSubmittedBallots(); ?>
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. So my question is, how would i go about displaying the $row array on my html page?

Comment: did you include that php file?

Comment: Probably one of the two "return false" happen before?

Comment: You can't use `$this` in a function that isn't part of a class. Did you pull this code out of a class?

Comment: Or if it is part of a class, you will need to create an instance of the class then call it for that instance. `$class = new Class(); $class->GetSubmittedBallots();`

Comment: I feel someone is going to shout out again, `Hey! DO NOT USE mysql_* functions anymore, all deprecated, auuwwww!!!`...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("methods.php"); // Include the file which has the "GetSubmittedBallots" function or method, if it's in a separate file

GetSubmittedBallots(); // Run the function / method
?>
```

If this doesn't work, please let us know any errors you receive.

Comment: <?PHP
require_once("./source/include/membersite_config.php");
require_once("./source/include/fg_membersite.php");

   if($fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
   }


?>

The class file is included already

Answer (score 0):

Does it echo "Array"?
That's because you are trying to echo an array.

You should use something like `print_r` or `var_dump`, given that you are just trying to access the queried results. In my opinion the method should build a multidimensional array with the records, and then the template logic should loop through them and echo the values in a nice way. Be it a table or nicely arranged HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, `$this` keyword is indicating you're in a class? If so, you need first to init that class and try to call `GetSubmittedBallots` function after init;

```
// assuming that class's name is Users
$users = new Users();
$users->GetSubmittedBallots();
```